# Issue with type force PATH search

Tags: bash, fish, shell-builtin

This is Bash. The behavior is similar in fish.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ alias py=python
$ type py
py is aliased to `python'
```

​And then, running `type -P py` prints nothing, where as I expected to print `/usr/bin/pyton` in a similar fashion to what is seen below.​

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ type -P ls
/bin/ls
```

The documentation for the `-P` option reads

```
  -P        force a PATH search for each NAME, even if it is an alias,
    builtin, or function, and returns the name of the disk file
    that would be executed
```

I've confirmed that `/usr/bin` (the directory where `python` is located) is in `PATH`.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

> force a PATH search for each NAME, even if it is an alias,

does not mean that bash will expand the alias and then search for the expanded command. It means that, if there were a command `foo`, and also an alias `foo`, the `type -P foo` will still look for the command named `foo`, even though there's an alias masking it. So bash isn't expanding `py` in `type -P py` to be `python`, and it won't show `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Seems clear enough. `NAME` is the argument to `type`, not an alias expansion of the argument.

Answer (score 4):

What’s going on is that your shell is looking for a binary named `py` in each directory on your `PATH`, and not finding any.

`type -P` doesn’t interpret aliases or functions; it forces the given name to be searched on the path, ignoring any other available command not of type “file” with the same name.

(There’s an added subtlety with `type -p` and `type -P`: they take hashes into account, so they will show a hashed value if one exists, without looking in the `PATH`. But that’s not involved here.)